# concatenate each element of character vector with all elements of a second vector r

Tags: r, vector, character, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two character vectors in a way that the following output is produced

```
aggmodes<-c("17x8","17x7x8","17x28x8")
listdata<-c("Motion.Age","res.Context.Only")
```

The output should be like this

```
"Motion.Age,17x8"  
"Motion.Age,17x7x8"
"Motion.Age,17x28x8"
"res.Context.Only,17x8"
"res.Context.Only,17x7x8"
"res.Context.Only,17x28x8"
```

I have written following code:

```
c<-as.vector(sapply(1:length(listdata), function(i){
sapply(1:length(aggmodes),function(j){paste(aggmodes,listdata)})
}))
```

but it gives me an a 10 dimensional vector. I am sorry if it is a duplicate, but i couldnot find a correct answer for solving my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c(sapply(listdata,paste,aggmodes,sep=","))
# [1] "Motion.Age,17x8"          "Motion.Age,17x7x8"        "Motion.Age,17x28x8"      
# [4] "res.Context.Only,17x8"    "res.Context.Only,17x7x8"  "res.Context.Only,17x28x
```

We paste each element of `listdata` to all of `aggmodes` with sapply, and then unwrap it all.

Your code is suboptimal because you don't leverage the fact `paste` is vectorized, however it can work with a slight modification:

```
as.vector(sapply(1:length(listdata), function(i){
  sapply(1:length(aggmodes),function(j){paste(aggmodes[j],listdata[i])})
}))
```

Comment: `sapply(listdata,paste,aggmodes,sep=",")` will give you a matrix, `lapply(listdata,paste,aggmodes,sep=",")` will give you two vectors in a list

Comment: I wanted to split the result of c<-c(sapply(listdata,paste,aggmodes,sep=",")) into two separate vectors, i tried this using ch<-unlist(lapply(c,strsplit,split=",")) but it created a single vector. I have to first join two vectors and then save them as separate vectors at a later time because the actual vectors are quite long

Comment: then `l <- lapply(listdata,paste,aggmodes,sep=",")`, and `v1 <- l[[1]]` and  `v2 <- l[[2]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
as.character(outer(listdata, aggmodes, paste, sep = ","))
```

`outer` takes three arguments: `x`, `y`, and `FUN`.  It applies `FUN` to all elements of `x` and `y` - in this case, pasting them together.  Since `outer` returns a matrix, wrap it in `as.character` to return a vector!